# MX Keys inconsistent and laggy response time on Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I am on ubuntu 22.04.1 and I am dual booting with Win 11. When in Ubuntu my MX Keys keyboard is laggy and with slow inconsistent resposne time. The keyboard works perfectly fine on Windows. Slow keys are turned off.
I did an online test for keyboard response time on https://blog.seethis.link/scan-rate-estimator/ and this is the result with the MX Keys (pressing only 'a' key). I tried to press the key in about the same intervals:
Key press history: 
a: 90ms 
a: 68ms 
a: 90ms 
a: 90ms 
a: 89ms 
a: 113ms 
a: 201ms 
a: 0ms 
a: 112ms 
a: 0ms 
a: 90ms 
a: 2ms 
You can see that it is very inconsistent. Extremely annoying especially when writing code.

The same test with my laptop's keyboard (while MX Keys are connected): 
Key press history: 
a: 42ms 
a: 58ms 
a: 78ms 
a: 81ms 
a: 69ms 
a: 77ms 
a: 74ms 
a: 79ms 
a: 69ms 
a: 62ms 
a: 68ms 
a: 71ms 
a: 62ms 
a: 30ms 
Much more consistent times. Just feels like instant response time.

I am connecting the MX Keys with Solaar. I am not using the USB UNIFYING RECEIVER.

Additional issue: the keyboard disconnects randomly about once a day. I should turn if off and on again to connect. But this does not bother me much.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Thanks for the scan rate estimator link. My rates are in 0-100ms region when hitting random characters on laptop keyboard, but up to 500-1000ms (!?) range when typing with my MX Keys Mini.

Comment: Do you have a bluetooth mouse connected? I have a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1463834/bluetooth-keyboard-input-lag-goes-away-if-bluetooth-mouse-disconnected-ubuntu) and it seems that powering off the bluetooth mouse makes the keyboard seemingly lag-free.